# c# parser for ActiproSyntaxEditor

Tags: c#, parsing

Is there any freeware c# parser that can be used as parser in ActiproSyntaxEditor control?

Answer (score 0):

Your first choice should be Mono if you are looking for a C# parser, as it is always updated to keep sync with Microsoft's C# compiler,

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Apr-27.html

However, you seems to ask for one that can work with SyntaxEditor. This is strange, as this control already has C# support,

> Syntax Languages
>
> Syntax languages are a core piece of the text/parsing
> framework. They basically encapsulate all functionality for a
> particular code language that is being used within a SyntaxEditor
> control. This is everything from various types of parsing all the way
> to simpler features like determining word breaks or performing line
> commenting.
>
> **Over 20 full source sample language definitions are included with
> SyntaxEditor for common languages like Assembly, Batch files, C, C++,
> C#,** CSS, HTML, INI files, Java, JScript, Lua, MSIL, Pascal, Perl, PHP,
> PowerShell, Python, RTF, SQL, VB.NET, VBScript, and XML. Custom
> language definition can easily be created, thereby making it possible
> to build a code editor for any proprietary language.

http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/controls/windowsforms/syntaxeditor/editing